# How to make promise-aware component without injecting a service?

Tags: ember.js, ember-components

I've just started learning Ember, and trying to create a table component. I want the table component to render loading/spinner while data is still fetching (promise is not yet fulfilled).

I found an example from a blog post - [Rendering a Promise Before it Resolves](http://emberigniter.com/render-promise-before-it-resolves/) - which works great. However, in my case I don't think table component would load data on its own. I think it would still more flexible to let route handles that.

Consequently, I look further and found another blog post - [Promise-aware controllers and components with Ember.js](http://blog.ksol.fr/promise-aware-controllers-and-components/). It does quite exactly on how would I prefer. However, I'm wondering if:

1. Is mixing PromiseProxyMixin into Component, a hack, or is this the way 
   it's designed to be used?
2. Is there anyway to change sending data through promise property. I think it is quite strange to do:

   {{ember-table promise=model.data}}

I tried using computed field to alias the name, promise to something else, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I think you could use "isFulfilled" hook . {{#if model.tableData.isFulfilled}} {{table-component}} {{else}} <span class="spinner"> {{/if}}

Comment: You're right about this thank! I was curious from your answer, so I looked more carefully and found that the object type returned from route was [DS.PromiseArray](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.PromiseArray.html), which uses PromiseProxyMixin! Thus, I could track promise life cycle just like I wanted to.

Comment: Btw if you're dealing with arrays you can use "length" property . {{#if data.length}} data loaded {{else}} icon {{/if}}

Answer (score 0):

Every model has an isLoaded property. So you can create a block component that will either display the model value, or a spinner if it isn't loaded yet.

```
//template consuming component
{{#loadingSpinner}}
  {{model.value}}
{{/loadingSpinner}}


//templates/components/loading-spinner.hbs
{{#if model.isLoaded}}
    {{yield}}
{{else}}
    //YOUR LOADING SPINNER GOES HERE
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Not if your model came from store, which is fundamentally a promise object, in my case, [DS.PromiseArray](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.PromiseArray.html) via *this.store.query*. Otherwise, your answer would work too.